# Chrome on Android failing to download server-side managed files

Tags: android, google-chrome, download, http-headers, android-download-manager

I have a application which needs to use server-side code to authenticate that the user is logged in to access a file, and then sends the file's MIME type and the file contents. This works great on all desktop browsers, and also on all mobile browsers (Opera, Firefox) **except** Chrome on Android.

The problem is that when a file download is attempted, the file will either go into the default Android download manager and stay "queued" forever, or if it is a PDF it will load the default PDF viewer, whatever that may be (Google PDF viewer, the related Drive PDF viewer, Adobe Acrobat,...) and say the file is invalid. However, when the file is an image, it opens perfectly well inside Chrome, whence it can downloaded without any problems.

So far I have tried providing different headers such as `Content-Length`, `Content-Disposition` (set to both *inline* and *attachment*), `Accept-Ranges` (set to *bytes*), and setting the `Content-Type` to plain *application/octet-stream*, all without success. This is all the code does, and I have actually noticed the same problem on other websites that do the same thing.

I have tried this on a HTC Nexus 9, LG G4 and OnePlus 3 running from Lollipop 5.0 to Marshmellow 6.0 with the same results

As it is unrealistic to force people to use other web browsers, especially as Chrome is by far the most popular (and normally default) browser on Android devices, I would really like to be able to solve this problem. As far as I've been able to find, there seems to be the rare mention on this on the internet, all with no real answer.

I don't exactly know what to provide to show the problem, as the code itself is somewhat irrelevant, as the browser just recieves the file and headers. I know that the files themselves are not corrupted, as they work everywhere else, and I have used online example files with no difference.